# SSRS 2008: show last item in group row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I would like to show the last/first item (depending on my sorting settings) in the expandable row of a group.

For example I've some values ordered by month/year. I would like to show the most recent value in the collapsed row of a group (the one with the + button on the left side).

Is that solution possible without repeating that value on the first line as you can see in the attached image?
[image: SSRS 2008 Report]

(Take a look only at the Mese(month) and Anno(year) values, don't look at other values that are wrong)

Comment: Could you please expand on your question and add more detail?  It's not clear enough for me to help you.

Comment: As you can see, I've made row groups based on "Cod. Commessa" value. The first row of the group is the row with + or - icon (I don't know how to call exactly that row). So, I would like to show in that row the first item of the group. For example the row with "mese" = 4, "anno"=2014 etc...
Then, when a user expand the group, start to see items from 3/2014 and not from 4/2014 as you can see in the image.

Comment: Ok, based on what you have stated, I added a solution example for you below.

Answer (score 0):

Example Solution:

1. Right click on "Reports" in the solution explorer and choose "Add New Reports".
2. Choose your datasource and click next.
3. copy your query in the "Query String" area (I used a query without parameters for simplicity sake).  Click Next.
4. Choose tabular and click next
5. Click on the field you want grouped in the "Available fields" area and then click on the group button so the field is placed under the group section.  Then put the rest of the fields under the Details section using the "Details" button.  Click next when done.
6. Choose "Stepped" and "Enable drilldown" then click the finished button
7. When you preview the report you will see everything you want, except that the first row does not appear while the drill down group is collapsed.
8. In the design view as shown below in the picture, add the fields to the group row (next to "WorkDate" in my example) for each field you want to show.
   [image]
9. Now you will see in the preview that the first row of the group will display while the group is collapsed.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. But in this way, if I will expand row, the first item of the group is again the same as I have in the "lightblue" row.

Comment: Very true, but you didn't state that you didn't want that to occur.  What you can do is hide those "group columns" based on when you click on the "+" symbol. Then the contents in the blue row will be hidden when it is expanded and you will still see the first row in the white detail area.